How with scout make date filter sending requests to meiliSearch?
In laravel 11 with laravel/scout 10.11  app sending requests to meiliSearch (Package version:"1.10.2")   I set 2 filters as :
    $this->dataFromMLS = Article::search($this->search, function($meiliSearch, string $query, array $options ) {
        $options['attributesToHighlight'] = ['title', 'text', 'text_shortly'];

        $options['sort'] = $this->setSort($options);
        $options = $this->setRatingFilters($options);
        $options = $this->setPublishedAtFilters($options);

        \Log::info(' -1 searchOnMLSServer $options::');
        \Log::info($options);
        return $meiliSearch->search($query, $options);

...

public function setRatingFilters(array $options): array
{
    if($this->ratingFrom > 0) {
        $options['filter'][] = ' rating >= '.$this->ratingFrom;
    }
    if($this->ratingTill > 0) {
        $options['filter'][] = ' rating <= '.$this->ratingTill;
            throw_if($this->ratingFrom > $this->ratingTill,
                new InvalidMeiliSearchParametersException('Invalid parameters : rating from can not be bigger rating till !'));
    }
    return $options;
}

public function setPublishedAtFilters(array $options): array
{
    if(!empty($this->publishedFrom)) {
        $options['filter'][] = ' published_at >= '.$this->publishedFrom->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    if(!empty($this->publishedTill )) {
        $options['filter'][] = ' published_at <= '.$this->publishedTill->format('Y-m-d');

        throw_if($this->publishedFrom->gte($this->publishedTill),
                new InvalidMeiliSearchParametersException('Invalid parameters : published from date can not be bigger published till !'));
    }
    return $options;
}

I check options content in log file :
array (
  'hitsPerPage' => 20,
  'page' => 1,
  'attributesToHighlight' =>
  array (
    0 => 'title',
    1 => 'text',
    2 => 'text_shortly',
  ),
  'sort' =>
  array (
    0 => 'rating:desc',
    1 => 'category_name:asc',
    2 => 'title:asc',
    3 => 'published_at:desc',
  ),
  'filter' =>
  array (
    0 => ' rating >= 20',
    1 => ' rating <= 80',
    2 => ' published_at >= 2024-08-21',
    3 => ' published_at <= 2025-03-21',
  ),
)

And I got error :
Found unexpected characters at the end of the filter: `00:00:00`. You probably forgot an `OR` or an `AND` rule.

Looks like I make invalid date comparison. Which code is valid ?
